# How to use RecyclerView.Adapter notifyItemInserted/Removed in a right way?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

For instance, you have an adapter and in onBindViewHolder method you set OnClickListener to some views (and do some actions there depending on view position). You should assign `final` to position param of method onBindViewHolder so it could be accessible from onClick().

After changing dataset (remove or add item in list) you call onItemInserted or onItemRemoved and this really adds/removes a view in the recyclerview, BUT it does not refresh other viewitems so when you click on a neighbor viewitem it will open a screen or show data with invalid index. To avoid this I basically call notifyDatasetChanged to call onBind to all visible views and remove/add some views.

So how to refresh other views when you call notifyItemInserted/removed or how to work with these methots appropriately?

Comment: this shouldn't be the case. It works properly. Post your code if you're having wrong index problem. Ideally it should be `list.remove(position);` then `notifyItemRemoved(position);`. This works fine for me.

Comment: You should use `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()` and not keep the final position yourself

Comment: after item removed use notifyItemRangeChanged(0,list.size());...and it will work

Comment: @DavidMedenjak you are right! Please convert your comment to answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assigning the position to a variable in `onBindViewHolder` will lead to an inconsistent state if items in the dataset are inserted or deleted without calling `notifyDataSetChanged`.

To use `onItemInserted` or `onItemRemoved` the data in the viewholder should remain consistent since it will not be redrawn and `onClick` would use this invalid position assigned *before* an item was added or removed.

For this and other use cases the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` provides methods to access its position and id:

Use `getAdapterPosition()` or `getItemId()` to get valid positions and ids.

Also have a look on the other methods available in [`RecyclerView.ViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html).

Answer (score 5):

So, the way I fix the problem I had is by changing the `position` into `viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()`

**Cheers!**

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to add notifyItemRangeChanged after insert or remove list inside adapter. This work for my project.

Example in remove item :

```
public void removeItem (int pos) {        
        simpanList.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, simpanList.size());//add here, this can refresh position cmiiw
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, this is what I do when inserting/removing in recyclerview
For example, my model class is `CarsModel`

In my adapter

```
    ArrayList<CarsModel> carsModel;
```

In onBindViewHolder

```
    CardModel model = carsModel.get(position);
```

When removing data in list using button in holder:

```
    int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    carsModel.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Then when inserting

```
    carsModel.add(0, model);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
```

or insert in last row

```
    carsModel.add(carsModel.size() - 1 , model);
    notifyItemInserted(carsModel.size()-1);
```