# How to getting the current value when i clicked my recycler view

Tags: android

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


private String[] mDatasetname;

private Integer[] mexp;
Context context;
public ToggleButton select;
Integer selectedcountint=0;
  private Bitmap[] mpro;

private String[] mloc;
private String[] mobj;

private String[] mselected;
 public ArrayList<String> nselected = new ArrayList<>();



public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView texp;
    public Button pdf;
    public ToggleButton select;
    public ImageView pro;
    public TextView loc;




    public MyViewHolder(View v){

        super(v);


        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
       texp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setexp);
        pdf = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.moreinfo);
        select = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.select);
        pro = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.setpropic);
        loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setlocation);



    }


}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset,Integer[] exp,Bitmap[] pro,String[] loc,String[] obj){


    mDatasetname = myDataset;

    mexp=exp;
    mpro=pro;
    mloc=loc;

    mobj=obj;



}



@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    context=parent.getContext();
    View vs = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(vs);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){




    holder.mTextView.setText(mDatasetname[position]);
    holder.texp.setText(String.valueOf(mexp[position])+" yrs");
    holder.pro.setImageBitmap(mpro[position]);
    holder.loc.setText(mloc[position]);
    holder.select.setText("rejected");

    holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent =  new Intent(context, PdfViewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("obj",mobj[position]);
            context.startActivity(intent);


        }
    });



    holder.select.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked==true) {
                holder.select.setChecked(true);
                holder.select.setText("selected");
              nselected.remove(mobj[position]+",rejected");
               nselected.add(mobj[position]+",selected");
                Log.d("dei", String.valueOf(nselected));
                selectedcountint=selectedcountint+1;

                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                //            intent.putExtra("quantity",Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)nselected);
                intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
                intent.putExtra("totalval",selectedcountint);

                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);


            } else {
                holder.select.setChecked(false);
                holder.select.setText("rejected");
                nselected.remove(mobj[position]+",selected");
                nselected.add(mobj[position]+",rejected");
                Log.d("dei", String.valueOf(nselected));
                selectedcountint=selectedcountint-1;


                Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                //            intent.putExtra("quantity",Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)nselected);
                intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
                intent.putExtra("totalval",selectedcountint);

                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);






            }
        }
    });







}


@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDatasetname.length; }
```

}

I have a recycler view in my app. I am having a problem. There is an item so that when I click on the item a the funtion in the click b is executed. It would be very great when you clean up the below code for me because I am new to programming, so that I won't be able to solve the problem.

Comment: You need to use the model class for it like this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51960700/3946958

Comment: What are you getting when you try to fetch the key "obj" in the PdfViewer Activity ?

Comment: string @SudhanshuVohra

Comment: @forfreelancer are you not getting the same string as in the obj[] array ?

Comment: yeah!!@SudhanshuVohra

Answer (score 1):

```
if(getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
  ...
  mobj[getAdapterPosition()]
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you set your data and listeners in the `ViewHolder`. You should create a method in your ViewHolder class and pass there item from your list as a parameter. In this method you copy all your code for setting text and listeners. Then in `onBindViewHolder` you call this method.

First create a class that will be our Adapter item (you should change the names of the fields because I don't know what should they represent, this is just an example):

```
class AdapterItem {

   private String firstString;
   private Integer integerValue;
   private Bitmap bitmap;
   private String secondString;
   private String thirdString;

   // create also getters, setters for fields
}
```

Your adapters constructor will look something like this:

```
public MyAdapter(ArrayList<AdapterItem> data){
   this.data = data;
}
```

And the `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.bind(data[position]);
}
```

In the ViewHolder class:

```
void bind(AdapterItem item) {
    mTextView.setText(item.getFirstString());

    pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, PdfViewer.class);
        intent.putExtra("obj", item.getThirdString());
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
   });

}
```

Comment: but all is fine set on click listner is doing the problem now . same as before@LaVepe

Comment: Use  getAdapterPosition() to get the position from ViewHolder

Comment: @forfreelancer what exactly is the problem now? You have trouble to get data from extras in second activity?

Comment: text view is working fine which is inside the bind method  but pdf.clicklistner is not working good because when i click that it gives me wrong data

Comment: Are you using `getIntent().getStringExtra("obj");` to get data from intent?

Comment: @forfreelancer refer to my answer and try it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you are passing 5 lists to your adapter, that's why my solution wasn't working. Usually, just one list is passed. Maybe you should consider merging this 5 lists into one list of your custom class. That class would have fields for your String, Integer, Bitmap data. I can edit my answer to explain more.

Comment: yeah can you please help me!!

Comment: @forfreelancer try it now :)

Comment: Sir there is no problem with that, but context is marked as error@LaVepe

Comment: Since you pass view object into your ViewHolder in constructor, you should be able to use `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: i can able to use only click listner view  and that view is  not working

Comment: Try to rename View in your `onClick(View v)` to `onClick(View view)` 
 because it can be clashing with your ViewHolders constructor view `MyViewHolder(View v)` and that's maybe why it's not working. In onClick then try to call `v.getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by @andrei The code to get the correct string from the obj[] array should be as shown:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] myDataset,Integer[] exp,Bitmap[] pro,String[] loc,String[] obj){
    mContext = context; // make mContext as a variable like others
    mDatasetname = myDataset;
    mexp=exp;
    mpro=pro;
    mloc=loc;
    mobj=obj;
}

    holder.pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent =  new Intent(context, PdfViewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("obj",mobj[holder.getAdapterPosition()]);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And similarly replace all occurrences of `position` with `holder.getAdapterPosition()` because `holder.getAdapterPosition()` will always give you the updated position for an item of recycler view in your code as if you update or delete items without using `notifyDataSetChanged()` method then the `onBindViewHolder` will not be called again hence the position will become inconsistent. For detailed information you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35812485/how-to-use-recyclerview-adapter-notifyiteminserted-removed-in-a-right-way).

Comment: Are you still getting wrong obj[] value for the clicked position in the next activity i.e. PdfViewer.class ?

Comment: @forfreelancer can you carefully inspect the error and then report what is the actual issue, is it wrong data item being sent or a compilation error

Comment: @forfreelancer see the updated answer, I have passed in the context of the activity instantiating the adapter as parameter and used it as the context

Comment: can we connect via team viewer sir?

Comment: @forfreelancer is the above method not working ? If not, then what is the error it is throwing now ?

Answer (score 0):

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private String[] mDatasetname;

private Integer[] mexp;
 private Context context;
public ToggleButton select;
Integer selectedcountint=0;
  private Bitmap[] mpro;

private String[] mloc;
private String[] mobj;
public Button pdf;Context m;private String[] mselected;
 public ArrayList<String> nselected = new ArrayList<>();



public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public CardView mCardView;
    public TextView mTextView;
    public TextView texp;
    public Button pdf;
    public ToggleButton select;
    public ImageView pro;
    public MainActivity activity;

    public  Context ipaset;
    public TextView loc;
    public View layout;

      View forresumeview;
    String forresume;
    private RecyclerView.ViewHolder s;




    public MyViewHolder(final View v) {

        super(v);


        mCardView = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        mTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_text);
        texp = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setexp);
        pdf = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.moreinfo);
        select = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.select);
        pro = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.setpropic);
        loc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setlocation);


        forresumeview=v;




    }




    void bind(String name, Integer exp, String location, final Bitmap image, final String obj ){
            mTextView.setText(name);

            texp.setText(String.valueOf(exp) + " yrs");
            pro.setImageBitmap(image);
            loc.setText(location);







    }

    public void doonce(final String s){


        pdf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vs) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(forresumeview.getContext(), PdfViewer.class);

                intent.putExtra("obj", s);


                forresumeview.getContext().startActivity(intent);


                //  Log.d("sdasd", obj);


            }
        });

    }




}

public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset,Integer[] exp,Bitmap[] pro,String[] loc,String[] obj){


    mDatasetname = myDataset;

    mexp=exp;
    mpro=pro;
    mloc=loc;

    mobj=obj;




}



@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

    context=parent.getContext();

   View vs = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(vs);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position){


    holder.bind(mDatasetname[position],mexp[position],mloc[position],mpro[position],mobj[position]);

    holder.doonce(mobj[position]);









}





@Override
public int getItemCount() { return mDatasetname.length; }
```

}

this is the answer ,,,,  it works i tried it !!!! Happy coding ......